# odbc_exec() returns resource(3) of type (odbc result) in False situation php access

Tags: php, ms-access

My code...

```
<?php

$parm1 = 8;

//Connect to our MS Access database
$conn=odbc_connect("archive","" ,"password");

//Create our SQL statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM archive where archiveID = $parm1" . " order by fullname desc";

//Execute our SQL statement
$row=odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

var_dump($row);

 echo "<option value=''>Select Local Archive Location</option>";

     if ($row !== False) { //if there are records, process them.


             while(odbc_fetch_row($row)){ //Iterate through all our records.

                 echo   "<option value='" .trim(odbc_result($row,"archivelocation"))."'>".trim(odbc_result($row,"fullname")).' - '.trim(odbc_result($row,"archivelocation")).' - '.trim(odbc_result($row,"archivedescription"))."</option>";
             }  
     }else{
                 echo   "<option value=''>No data returned for the specified search criteria</option>"; 
     }


odbc_close($conn); //Close our database connection.


?>
```

When the above code runs and there is data to be returned the value of $row is resource(3) of type (odbc result). Which I understand to be correct. However when a False value is expected for $row I am still getting the same value resource(3) of type (odbc result) in a False situation.

Can anybody explain why this is?

Comment: Do you get into the `else`, so the option with the specified text is echoed?

Comment: no It appears it does not get into the else statement

Comment: David Egan. How do you process queries with the ODBC when your parameter is a string? I am having a hard time getting it to work through exec().

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual:

> Returns an ODBC result identifier if the SQL command was executed successfully, or FALSE on error.

So you will always get an ODBC result identifier, except there was an actual error. Even when you have an empty resultset, $row will still be not equal to `false`. If you want to check wether there are any results, you should do it the following way:

```
if ($row !== false && odbc_num_rows($row) > 0) { //if there are records, process them.

  while(odbc_fetch_row($row)){ //Iterate through all our records.

    echo "<option value='" .trim(odbc_result($row,"archivelocation"))."'>".trim(odbc_result($row,"fullname")).' - '.trim(odbc_result($row,"archivelocation")).' - '.trim(odbc_result($row,"archivedescription"))."</option>";
  }
}else{
  echo   "<option value=''>No data returned for the specified search criteria</option>"; 
}
```

Comment: After trying the above, The else side worked. However the true side stopped working.

Comment: I do apologies Tobias the above code worked perfectly. I tried it again. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Now contrary to Tobias's answer above under testing I realised this was not working. In order to get the right answer I had to modify the code. The following answer works.

```
<?php

$parm1 = intval($_GET['q']);

//Connect to our MS Access database
$conn=odbc_connect("archive","" ,"password");

//Create our SQL statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM archive where archiveID = $parm1" . " order by fullname desc";

//Execute our SQL statement
$row=odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

echo "<option value=''>Select Local Archive Location</option>";

     if (odbc_fetch_row($row)) { //Retrieve our first record, if any.

                do {

                    echo    "<option value='" .trim(odbc_result($row,"archivelocation"))."'>".trim(odbc_result($row,"fullname")).' - '.trim(odbc_result($row,"archivelocation")).' - '.trim(odbc_result($row,"archivedescription"))."</option>";

                } while (odbc_fetch_row($row));
     }else{
                    echo    "<option value=''>No data returned for the specified search criteria</option>"; 
     }


odbc_close($conn); //Close our database connection.


?>
```